# INSERT conflict with FOREIGN KEY restrictions

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012, insertion

Well, I'm stuck with some silly problem. In SQL Server 2012 I am trying to implement the city database like this: there's a `City` object, a `Street` object which points to `City` where the street is placed, and a `House` object which points to `Street` where the house is placed.

So what I write:

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
    CityID      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    CityName    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(CityID)
)

INSERT INTO City VALUES 
    (1, 'Moscow'),
     -- Code for 2-7id's instructions is there
    (8, 'Kazan');

CREATE TABLE Street 
(
    StreetID    INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    StreetName  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CityID      INTEGER     NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY(CityID) REFERENCES City(CityID),
    PRIMARY KEY(StreetID)
)

INSERT INTO Street VALUES
        (1, 'Nation Street', 1),
         -- code for 2-19 id's insertions is there
        (20, 'Fuj Street', 8);

CREATE TABLE House 
(
    HouseID     INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    StreetID    INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    Height      INTEGER     NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (StreetID) REFERENCES Street(StreetID),
    PRIMARY KEY(HouseID)
)

INSERT INTO House VALUES 
    (1, 1, 100),
    -- ...
```

There's a bug in a first insertion `INSERT INTO HOUSE VALUES`, and the compiler says that there's some restriction conflict for `INSERT` and `FOREIGN KEY`, but I totally don't understand what he is complaining about.

The all data is in the table actually, so why I can't just simply do the insertion?

What is the solution of this problem?

Error message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint  The conflict occurred in database ,..., table "dbo.Street", column 'StreetID'

Comment: Maybe pasting the error message and not what you remember from it would help... don't be a silly user, try to take as much as possible from error messages.

Comment: You should specify field order in your INSERT statements: `INSERT INTO House (HouseID, StreetID, Height) VALUES 
    (1, 1, 100),`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae5a4/1 . With the sample datas given, works like a charm ! So give all your code, maybe...

Comment: are u sure that all the values in the INSERT INTO HOUSE are correct. You did not show all of them right ?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're trying to insert a home with a street id that doesn't exist in your street table...

Comment: Except that there appears to be a corresponding record in the street table.

Comment: well, SQL isn't trying to bother you. The message is classic, and quite clear, so there must be something wrong with the data. Try isolating the line with the problem by commenting half of your insert values, identifying if the problematic line is in the commented block or not, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The StreetID which is present there in your House table does not contain in the street table....so please check whether the same streetId is present in both the table

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Instead of INSERT without column name.
As it seems, when to Insert without column names, your first values in Street, align with StreetID, which does not have id higher than 8.

```
INSERT INTO Street VALUES
        (1, 'Nation Street', 1),
         -- code for 2-19 id's insertions is there
        (20, 'Fuj Street', 8);
```

It violates the RESTRICT INSERT property of the FOREIGN KEY. declare the column names as my first INSERT example, then your insert will work fine.